# CSS Background Images Not Appearing on Mobile (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, css, html, mobile, background

I have a header and several divs with background images that are not appearing on my mobile device (iPhone 5). Here is an example:

CSS:

```
#title_img {
    background: url("title.png") no-repeat scroll center top / 100% auto transparent;
    height: 125px;
}
```

The site I am working on is responsive, so at reduced window sizes, I reduce the size of height of the header:

```
#title_img {
    height: 80px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header id="title_img" role="banner"></header>
```

A blank space where the image should be.

I also have several divs that use the similar CSS for displaying background images that are not appearing on the device. The images are all in the same directory as the CSS file. There is one image that is called through an  tag in the HTML and it displays fine on iPhone. Thanks!

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image? Is it beyond Mobile Safari's supported dimensions?

Comment: Definitely within the supported dimensions. Some of the undisplayed images are only 64x64px. The also don't display in the Chrome app for the iPhone.